# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - although value exists in referenced table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, foreign-key

I am trying to insert a row into a table that has a foreign key constraint, with below query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (
    ID, 
    tNum, 
    CompanyID,           -- this column has foreign key on it

    Date, 
    Type, 
    RowDate, 
    App)
SELECT 
    121801947, 
    tNum, 
    218,                 -- this value throws foreign key error

    GETDATE(), 
    Type, 
    GETDATE(), 
    'Manual'
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = 123533336
AND Type = 1
```

And it throws error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Table1_Companies". The conflict occurred in database "MainDB", table "dbo.Companies", column 'cid'.

Table1 references Companies table with below foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Companies] 
FOREIGN KEY([CompanyID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([cid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_Companies]
```

When I run below:

```
select * from Companies where cid = 218
```

It actually has the row with cid = 218
So what is going on here ?

Comment: could it be that you're running `select * from Companies where cid = 218` from a session where there's an open transaction which inserted the cid 218 but has not been committed and the insert is being executed on a different session?

Comment: @Ronaldo no, row with cid = 218 has been there for ages; there wasn't any session that inserted cid 218

Comment: Any (INSERT) triggers on the table?

Comment: Is there a second Companies table in your default schema?  eg `select * from sys.tables where name = 'Companies'`

Comment: Is CompanyID defined with the same data type in both tables?